# Run Static Method on Parent from Child inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, static-methods

I have the following code:

```
class Base { 

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.table)
  }

  static getAll() { 
    console.log("select * from " + this.table);
  }
}

class User extends Base { 
  static table = 'user'
}
class Room extends Base { 
  static table = 'room'
}

let user = new User()
let room = new Room()

User.getAll()
Room.getAll()
```

output:

```
undefined
undefined
select * from user
select * from room
```

the method getAll works and returns "Select * from User" 
but, the same field is not accessible, at least I could not on the constructor.

how can I access this static field? 
thank you

Comment: `Base` does not have a `table` property? You probably meant `this.table`

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question :)

Comment: Now you're looking for `this.constructor.table`. Or, specifically in the constructor, also `new.target.table`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use child props from a parent class. If you wish to use some prop in all child classes then add it to a parent class. Otherwise your class hierarchy has wrong architecture. A base class shouldn't know anything about child classes.

Comment: Sorry, what I want is access the child static field "table" from the Base
I'm able to access it on the method getAll()
but on the constructor, the line: console.log(this.table) returns undefined

alsom I don't want to use User, because I will have multiples tables

Comment: I don't want the base class to know nothing from the Child.

When I run User.getAll() it invokes the Base method and even in the base Method, it know the current method is from a User and the this.table works

but the same does not happen when I'm creating the instance (probably because this in the constructor has another meaning)